# Passing HTTP Headers from AWS API to Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, http-headers, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get the HTTP headers and body details in AWS Lambda function using java, which are sent by POST method using AWS API. So far, I have successfully setup the connection between AWS API and AWS Lambda Function and am able to invoke it from the API Gateway. Now to pass headers to the Lambda function, I have done all the steps before "Updating lambda function" from [here](https://kennbrodhagen.net/2015/12/02/how-to-access-http-headers-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda/). Following is My lambda code:

```
    import com.amazonaws.Request;
    import com.amazonaws.Response;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event;

    public class SimpleSysout implements RequestHandler<Request, String> {
        public String handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {
            System.out.println("Method = "+request.getHttpMethod());
            System.out.println("Headers= "+request.getHeaders().toString());
            System.out.println("Content= "+request.getContent().toString());
            System.out.println("Servcie Name = "+request.getServiceName().toString());
            System.out.println("Resource Path = "+request.getResourcePath().toString());
            return request.toString();
        }

    }
```

But I get error like

```
    {
      "errorMessage": "An error occurred during JSON parsing",
      "errorType": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
      "stackTrace": [],
      "cause": {
        "errorMessage": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.amazonaws.Request, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@4dfa3a9d; line: 1, column: 1]",
        "errorType": "java.io.UncheckedIOException",
        "stackTrace": [],
        "cause": {
          "errorMessage": "Can not construct instance of com.amazonaws.Request, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@4dfa3a9d; line: 1, column: 1]",
          "errorType": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
          "stackTrace": [
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:889)",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I have also tried using different parameters instead of the Request, such as events, but none of them work.

Comment: Can you post your mapping template.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with you payload mapping template. During the API gateway setup you can specify how do you want to map the request to the event. There are also a couple of pre-made templates you can select from.

Take a look at this doc from Amazon:

[API Gateway API Request and Response Payload-Mapping Template Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

### handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream,Context context)

I let you a link where is the correct implementation to get your headers from a JSON.

https://www.baeldung.com/aws-lambda-api-gateway